# An explicit matrix form

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-groups, involutions, classical-groups, centralisers

In the algebraic group $G=\operatorname {PCGO}(2m,K)$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field of an odd characteristic, there is a conjugacy class of involutions with representative:
$$
 e=\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -wI_m & 0 \\
    0 & wI_m \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]$$ where $w$ is of order 4 in $K$.

The centralizer in $G$ is $C_G(e) =A_{m-1}T_1.2$. The "$2$" acts on $A_{m-1}$ as a graph automorphism and inverts the $T_1$ (one-dimensional torus).

Is there an explicit matrix form of the generator of the "$2$" group?

$G=\operatorname {PCGO}(2m,K)$ is the group which fixes a non-degenerate quadratic from up to a scalar.

Comment: In the coördinates used for your matrix realisation, what is your orthogonal form?  The one with matrix $\operatorname{antidiag}(1, \dotsc, 1)$? \\ I am used to CO (for conformal orthogonal) and GO (for general orthogonal), but why CGO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are working with respect to the orthogonal form with matrix $\begin{pmatrix} & w_0 \\ w_0 \end{pmatrix}$, where $w_0 = \operatorname{antidiag}(1, \dotsc, 1)$.  That's the one that I'm used to, so it works for me.

$\operatorname{GL}_m$ embeds in $\operatorname{SO}_{2m}$ as $g \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} g \\ & \tau(g) \end{pmatrix}$, where $\tau : g \mapsto \operatorname{Int}(w_0)g^{-\mathsf T}$ is an outer involution of $\operatorname{GL}_m$.  This embedding gives the isomorphism $\operatorname{GL}_m/\mu_2 \cong \operatorname C_{\operatorname{PGO}_{2m}}(e)^\circ$.

The non-identity component of $\operatorname C_{\operatorname{PGO}_{2m}}(e)$ contains the image in $\operatorname{PGO}_{2m}(e)$ of $\begin{pmatrix} & I_m \\ I_m \end{pmatrix}$, which may therefore be taken as an explicit matrix form of a generator of the "2" in which you are interested.

By the way, this is all probably easiest to picture when $m = 1$, when the images in $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ of $\begin{pmatrix} i \\ & -i \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are the classical example of commuting, semisimple elements that do not belong to a common torus.

Comment: Thank you for the input. If my form is $$\Delta \left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]_m,$$ would the answer be$$\Delta \left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \right]_m$$ instead?

Comment: @scsnm, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463482/an-explicit-matrix-form/463484#comment1203346_463484), I don't understand your notation.  What is $\Delta[\cdot]_m$?

Comment: Sorry about that. It means $m$-copies embedded diagonally.

Comment: @scsnm, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463482/an-explicit-matrix-form/463484#comment1203352_463484), then I don't understand what it means for the form to be $\Delta\left[\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}\right]_m$.  An orthogonal form should have a symmetric matrix.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't realize I put the group $G$ mistakenly. It is supposed to be a symplectic group. I will write another question. So sorry.